# How to return a objects from a Django model based on date

Tags: django, django-models

> I have a function in models.py below that I want to use to return a list of events whos dates are less than todays date (meaning they have not happend yet) and not return them if the date has passed and then display it in index.html with a for loop

## Index.html

```
<!-- Events section -->
<section class="container text-center">
    <h1 class="section-title"><span class="st-span">Upcoming Events</span></h1>
        {% if events %}
            {% for event in events.get_upcoming_events %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="card-img-top dropshadow" src="{% static 'core/images/banner/carousel-1.jpg' %}" alt="Event image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 m-auto px-5">
                            <h4 class="card-title border-bottom pb-3"><strong>{{ event.title }}</strong></h4>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ event.description|truncatechars:255 }}</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'event-detail' event.title %}">View Event</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>No events at the moment, please check back regulary for updates</p>
        {% endif %}
</section>
```

## Models.py

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
import datetime as dt

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.CharField(default='', max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Start Date', default=now)
    start_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Start Time', default=now)
    end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='End Date', default=now)
    end_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='End Time', default=now)
    # add event image field
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

    def has_not_ended(date):
        if date < dt.date.today():
            return False
        return True

    def get_upcoming_events(self):
        upcoming_event_list = []
        for event in Event.objects.all():
            if Event.has_not_ended(event.end_date):
                upcoming_event_list.append(event)
        return upcoming_event_list
```

Comment: "to return a list of events whos dates are less than todays date (meaning they have not happend yet)" if an event's date is before/less than today, then surely it has already happened as is not a future/upcoming event?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually using this property to do exactly what you are doing:

```
@property
def is_past_due(self):
    return timezone.now() > self.end_date
```

it could substitute your `has_not_ended`.

Then you should be creating a separate function for the `get_upcoming_events`. Because if you set it as a function inside the model, it should be a relation for each object of that model, and this is not the case, so:

```
# separate from the model!
def get_upcoming_events():
        upcoming_event_list = []
        for event in Event.objects.all():
            if Event.is_past_due: # here you use the new property of your model
                upcoming_event_list.append(event)
        return upcoming_event_list
```

Then you can call this function on any of your views and it will give you the events. If you want to print it on a template you just have to send the returned list as a context.

I hope this is what you needed.